# Remove empty self-closing paragraph elements in text with some issues

Tags: regex, xslt

I accepted a task I thought was just writing an xsl using and overriding the identity rule:
The removal of empty self-closing paragraph elements
    `<p />` 
from multiple text files.

After some work with the texts, I realized that if I would remove all paragraph elements, this would make parts of the text unreadable.

One idea is to try to remove only those `<p />` that are inside a sentence, but since not all sentences are terminated by a . this is not so easy.
Another issue when removing `<p />` is that I get double whitespace in some places and no whitespace in some places.

I also have the feeling I might be removing more than `<p />`, but I could not get the template to match just p.

I could really use some advice here. What is the best I can achieve with this material?

A sample of the text file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Text number="1">
    <Title>Lazy dog jumper</Title>
    <Description><arg format="x" /><p /> The quick <p /> brown fox <p /> jumps <p /> over the <p /> lazy dog.<p />The quick brown fox jumps <p />over the lazy dog.<p /> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. <p /></Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="2">
    <Title>Lazy foxer</Title>
    <Description>The quick brown fox <arg format="x" /><p />jumps over the lazy dog <p /></Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="3">
    <Title>Quickest jumper</Title>
    <Description>The quickest brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <p /> The slowest brown fox jumps over the laziest dog.  <p /></Description>
  </Text>
</Data>
```

The xls (just identity rule and overriding this rule):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(.//@*)]"/>

    <!-- This is not matching <p /> ! -->
    <xsl:template match="p" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Text number="1">
    <Title>Lazy dog jumper</Title>
    <Description><arg format="x" />.<p />The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="2">
    <Title>Lazy foxer</Title>
    <Description>The quick brown fox <arg format="x" /> jumps over the lazy dog.</Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="3">
    <Title>Quickest jumper</Title>
    <Description>The quickest brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />The slowest brown fox jumps over the laziest dog.</Description>
  </Text>
</Data>
```

Since I cannot determine where the real paragraphs are in the text I do not dare removing the paragraphs at an end of a sentence. The only exception to this is the last sentence for each description text fragment. I added the missing full stop to the sentence, where I could guess there should be one.

Comment: What is the expected result in your example?

Comment: The self-closing paragraph tags scattered inside a sentence are making the files not so readable, so I guess if I start removing those, it will be an improvement to readability. These files are translated in a number of languages. I guess if a full stop is missing, to indicate the end of a sentence, these files will need a language review anyway.

Comment: I am afraid you're missing my point. Please edit your question and show the result (code) you expect to get as the output if the XSL transformation.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that. Now I have added an example of the desired output. I will keep this in mind when posting questions in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a case where you'd want to use a Regex (such as `\<p\s+?\/\>[ ]?`) as your replacement search (https://regex101.com/r/yG6hM5/1).  This is because you want to remove that trailing space if it's there from the empty `p` tag.  It would not capture a situation like `<p></p>` or `<p>   </p>` though.

This might be tough to do in XSLT since you also want to get rid of the space after an empty `p` tag.  You could try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()[local-name()!='p']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[text() != '']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZJ

but it won't get rid of that extra space.

The idea is to exclude all `p` nodes from your identity template, and have an additional template to match `p` tags whose text content isn't empty.  If you want to exclude something like `<p>   </p>` as well, you could change that second template to `p[normalize-space(text()) != '']`.

Comment: I have done some experimenting with multiple <xsl:template match="p[xx]"> templates and it seems to be possible to do a lot of readability improvements to the texts I am processing. Good tools you were linking to, thanks!